# Worksheet.SelectionChange get lost after some time

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

In a VSTO addin for Excel, developed in C#, I am creating a sheet this way:

```
public void Populate(List<Systems.Models.Producto> productos)
{
    Excel.Workbook workbook = _excelApp.ActiveWorkbook;
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets.Add(After: workbook.Sheets[workbook.Sheets.Count]);
    worksheet.SelectionChange += Worksheet_SelectionChange;
    worksheet.Name = "Inventario";
    // More instructions
}
```

Well... I have noticed that `Worksheet_SelectionChange` is called for a moment when I select any cell in the sheet. After a few minutes later, that event is not called anymore.

At first, I thought that the object that owns the method `populate`  was being disposed. That could sound strange since this object owns the sheet also so that while the sheet is not closed, the object will be alive. However, just in case, I have declared the object that owns the method `populate` globally to the parent object, but the same problem occurs.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare the source object at the global scope to get the event fired and prevent the source object from being swiped by the garbage collector from the heap:

```
Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
public void Populate(List<Systems.Models.Producto> productos)
{
    workbook = _excelApp.ActiveWorkbook;
    worksheet = workbook.Sheets.Add(After: workbook.Sheets[workbook.Sheets.Count]);
    worksheet.SelectionChange += Worksheet_SelectionChange;
    worksheet.Name = "Inventario";
    // More instructions
}
```

As you can see the `worksheet` object is declared at the class level, not method. That means you will get the event fired as long as the class instance exists.

Comment: Thanks... I have only declared worksheet at the class level and it seems to work. I will do more tests though. I used only worksheet since the workbook is not an instance created at that method. It already exists in ActiveWorkbook. I never create it explicitly since when Excel is launched and create a new sheet, a default workbook is also created.